# Change print method from PDF to default printer for a form printout

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am trying to get the print out of a userform. While printing its always prompting to save the userform (a prompt box is being displayed). I don't want it.

I want to get the printout directly after choosing the printer without saving it.

Code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    CommandButton2.Visible = False
    CommandButton1.Visible = False

    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrinterSetup).Show
    Me.PrintForm

    CommandButton2.Visible = True
    CommandButton1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried Application.DisplayAlerts = False, just before the PrintForm line?

Comment: Hi.No .Even adding this is not helping

Answer (score 1):

You may not like this answer, because it involves more workt, but you probably want the userform to add the data into a formatted worksheet and then use the printout method of the worksheet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/sheets-printout-method-excel

```
Worksheets.("yourWorksheet").printout _
 activeprinter:= yourPDFprinter, _
 PrintTofFile:= True, _
 PrToFileName:= filePathAndName
```

If you want to do it through the UserForm, you're probably going to end up making a bunch of Windows API calls.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code you can force a workbook to close without saving any changes, type the following code in a Visual Basic module of that workbook:

```
Sub Auto_Close()
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

Because the Saved property is set to True, Excel responds as though the workbook has already been saved and no changes have occurred since that last save.

**EDIT:**

Now I know what you're after I am going to presume you've created a button press for your form, so I think something like https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/544657-specifying-printer-printing-userform-using-vba.html . This will help you with what you want, as it will show you how to change the default print method, form PDF.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I want to print the userform not the excel sheet.Its like i want to print the document without saving it.Is it possible?everytime its asking to print the document without saving

Comment: Is this a userform within an excel workbook? if it is then what this will do is allow you to close the workbook without saving as then you can Dim the workbook and wb.close

Comment: Yes the userform is in the excel workbook.And i need to take the printout of userform not excel sheet.

Comment: Soory for the confusion.While i am printing the userform,the default option is " saving as pdf".I want to pass a default printer name.SO on clicking on print button,it should directly connect to the printer and print it